# Not installing as root

Tags: linux, software-installation, root

I read and understand that installing as root is not "good practice", however.

Some installations require sudo install.

Which part of the installation steps should be installed with sudo?

By example [this](https://github.com/JamesKegel/Sleepnet/blob/master/Install.script)

The guy says this is example of installing as root, and to not do this.

I am fairly new to linux, but this is one thing that hasn't fully clicked with me yet and would really like to have a confidence with installation of such things.

I have sought information online without anything fully detailing this exact scenario.

Comment: The question is too broad, and the answers will depend on personal opinion. Install _what_? Most software on Unix may be installed without root access (e.g. in one's `$HOME`).

Comment: perhaps my question is more, is root == sudo or or they respective of one another?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "run this" in the linked instructions refers to running the streaming server, not the whole set of instructions — you certainly can't run the apt-get commands as another user.

Comment: Nearly all package managers needs root privileges to run. So not installing as root is bad, permanent working as root is a problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You often have no other choice than to install as root, as package-managers demands it - at least on Linux-systems.  There are however other OS (like Solaris and OpenInidiana) where typical "root-privileges" have been split into separate privileges, so that installing (at least some) programs does not require root-privileges and can be delegated to other users without giving the full root-privileges.

You can set-up a Linux-system "cleverly" by using `sudo`, system-users/groups and carefully set permission for parts of the file-system.  For example, it's suggested that the **staff**-group in Debian owns */home* and */local* (and it's subdirs).  Thus members of **staff** - which should be "junior-administrators" on the current computer - could add home-directories for new users and add locally-built packages - which typically should be installed under */usr/local/*.

And if a package just contains a couple of binaries, it may be "installed manually" by simply copying the binaries to */usr/bin* - and this could be done by first using `sudo -i` to become **root**, then immediately using `su - bin` to become the less-privileged **bin**-user (which traditionally owns all *bin*-directories, and thus may copy files to them). Since you first became **root**, you don't need a password to become **bin**.  Similarly, you could become **adm** before looking at */var/log* or **mail** before looking around in */var/mail*.  This way, you only take the privileges you need to fix things where you actually are (or rather, should be).

+++

When it comes to locally built packages, you should *never* do this as **root**.  Download the package and unpack it as a *normal* user.  Then `configure` and `make` (the actual compiling) it - still as a normal user.  If you need to test it, test it as a *normal* user.  Only the `make install`-command actually requires **root**-privileges, so only then should you use `sudo`.

If you install the package only for yourself (your own home-dir), you don't need to become **root** at all.  Neither should you have to become root to "install" it so you can then create a binary-package of it.  You only need to become **root** to actually install the package you created system-wide with the package-manager.

+++

So you need to become **root** to install binary-packages with the package-manager or to install locally-built packages with `make install`.  But everything else - downloading, configuring, building, testing and creating a package - does *not* require you becoming **root**... and therefore, you *should not* do this as **root**!