# Installing ufw as root vs installing using sudo

Tags: software-installation, root, ufw

Is there any security issue if I installed `ufw` as root instead of a non-root user using sudo?
I checked [Not installing as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342878/not-installing-as-root) but the answer related to what I am installing as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

The `sudo` command typically provides "*one command at a time*" root access. Running a command directly as root, and running that same command with `sudo` as a normal user is directly equivalent.

```
# Run this as root
id

# Run this as a normal user who has "sudo" rights
sudo id
```

Both will give the same answer; that the `id` program is running as root

Answer (score 1):

No, these two approaches are the very same in effect. As you get the same result, there is no system-related difference.

---

The only user-related difference is, that you did enter `root` account some way, nowadays typically with `sudo -i` or similar rather than using `su`, but that is not what you asked.